# Titanium HTTPClient work too fast

Tags: android, ios, titanium, httpclient

This is my function.
I'm finding it difficult because the opening of the new page , call the w.open , I cannot synchronize with the server load, in fact, the opening of the page.
Thanks so much.

```
 function doLogin(e){
    var url = "http://www.myserver;
    var tableData = [];
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    };
    xhr.open("GET",url);
    xhr.send(); 

    LO.show({
        message: 'Wait..',
        messageRelevance: 3,
        cancelable: true
    });
    var w = Alloy.createController('personalhome').getView();
    w.addEventListener('open', function(){ LO.hide(); });
    w.open();   

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open you windows in the onload function instead of directly

```
function doLogin(e){
    var url = "http://www.myserver;
    var tableData = [];
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var w = Alloy.createController('personalhome').getView();
    w.addEventListener('open', function(){ LO.hide(); });
    w.open();   
    };
    xhr.open("GET",url);
    xhr.send(); 

    LO.show({
        message: 'Wait..',
        messageRelevance: 3,
        cancelable: true
    });
```

}

Thanks